# Howto get local Jenkins with branch in local mercurial repository to work?

Tags: windows, path, jenkins, mercurial

I have set up a local jenkins with mercurial plug in that should clone a local repository, i.e. `Repository URL = C:\repo` is a local path. I work on a branch, that's why I also added `branch = myBranchName`, but I don't believe this causes my problems.

If I start the job an error occurs and in the console I find (translated by me)

```
started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\jenkins\jobs\LocalRepo\workspace
$ hg clone --rev myBranchName --noupdate C:\repo C:\jenkins\jobs\LocalRepo\workspace
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 7905 changesets with 42182 changes to 10043 files
[workspace] $ hg update --rev myBranchName
abort: C:\jenkins\jobs\LocalRepo\workspace\Server/src/main/resources/com/application/resources/FileWithReallyReallyReallyReallyLongFileName.properties: The system cannot find the given path
ERROR: Failed to update C:\repo to rev myBranchName
Finished: FAILURE
```

I can reproduce the error in the command console with mercurial (translated again):

```
/cygdrive/c/jenkins/jobs/LocalRepo/workspace $ hg branch
default
/cygdrive/c/jenkins/jobs/LocalRepo/workspace $ hg hg update -C
Cancel: C:\jenkins\jobs\LocalRepo\workspace\Server/src/main/resources/com/application/resources/FileWithReallyReallyReallyReallyLongFileName.properties: The system cannot find the given path
```

The file really exists under `C:\repo` but not under the cloned directory C:\jenkins\jobs\LocalRepo\workspace.

What am I doing wrong? The absolute path is in my real application 269 chars long. Is that really the problem? Is that no problem for mercurial in the real repository `C:\repo` because jenkins writes the file in the deeper and longer path `C:\jenkins\jobs\LocalRepo\workspace\`? If that really is the problem how could I solve it best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The absolute path is in my real application 269 chars long. Is that really the problem

Yes. [The maximum path length in Windows is 260 characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx#maxpath).

Comment: I thought Windows 7 got better :( There's no chance to solve this other than shorten the path, right? Likely to occur again...

Comment: The path length limitation can't be fixed without breaking backwards compatibility because many existing applications store paths in arrays of length 260. So yes, you'll always need to keep path length limited on windows.

Comment: Than add a parameter `allowLongerPaths` and make the user decide this themself. 260 is really short today...

Comment: That's effectively the situation today. You can create longer paths if you use the right routines in the Windows API because NTFS supports it, but then these files become invisible to anything that uses the traditional APIs. Needless to say, doing this breaks lots of things so it's not a solution. We're stuck with this forever until Windows disappears.